# Searching for a number among the integers elements of array

Tags: c#

Searching for a "magic digit" among the integers elements of array and summing  of all integers that contain the "magic digit".

For example :

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 55
and magic Digit is 5

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 55
The sum of numbers that contain the magic digit "5" is: 60

---

(thank you in advance for your help)
so far I have :

```
       int[] arrayOfUserInput = new int[10];
       int i;

        //------------------------------- Array and variable declaration

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 integers : ");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("array element = {0} : ", i);
            arrayOfUserInput[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //-------------------------------- User input of 10 integers


        Console.Write("Please enter your magic number : ");
        int magicNumberInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (magicNumberInput >= 0 && magicNumberInput <= 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Your magic number is : {magicNumberInput}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but please enter single digit number!");
        }

        //-------------------------------- User input & displaying of magic number

        Console.WriteLine("Your integers are : ");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        Console.Write("{0}  ", arrayOfUserInput[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");

        //--------------------------------- Displaying user input of 10 integers
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: the task is quite complex, I've already done all the parts except one: I don't know how to pull and sum values from an array contain a magic digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.Where?view=netcore-3.1) and [`.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1) to calculate total of all numbers containing magic numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var arrayOfUserInput = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 55};
var magicNumberInput = 5;

var sumOfNumbers = arrayOfUserInput
    .Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(magicNumberInput.ToString()))  //Filter by Magic numbers
    .Sum();                                             //Calculate sum of filtered numbers.
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iRHOVl)

---

If you don't want to use Linq then you can do it using `foreach` or `for` loop with [`string.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1) function.

```
...
var sumOfNumbers = 0;
foreach(var input in arrayOfUserInput)
{
     if(input.ToString().Contains(magicNumberInput.ToString()))
          sumOfNumbers += input;
}

Console.WriteLine(sumOfNumbers);
```

I would strongly suggest you to read more about [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) and basics of C#.

---

**Code refactoring note:**

If you store input data in string format, then you need not to convert it again into string. At the time of addition convert it into `int` and add it to `sumOfNumbers`. Like,

Using Linq,

```
 var sumOfNumbers = arrayOfUserInput
     .Select(x => x.Contains(magicNumberInput) && int.TryParse(x, out int number) ? number : 0)
    .Sum();
```

using for loop,

```
...
var sumOfNumbers = 0;
foreach(var input in arrayOfUserInput)
{
     if(input.Contains(magicNumberInput) && int.TryParse(input, out int number))
          sumOfNumbers += number;
}
```

Comment: You should convert the magic number to a string once and store it in a variable instead of converting it for every single element in `Where`/`Contains`.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you @Abion47, but if we do this then OP need to rewrite code from start and refactoring of code and changing data type of input array will lead this topic to somewhere else. To avoid this situation I explain what was necessary and topic which OP asked it in his question. I also mentioned to read basic of C#. So that he/she can do refactoring by himself

Comment: If you think, I should add refactoring and correcting his code in the same answer, then I am ready to do that

Comment: @Abion47, I updated my answer. Now my solution converts string to int only once